# Implement qrview for TargetPlatform.linux to Scan QR Code in Flutter

Tags: flutter, qr-code, target-platform

I wish to scan a QR Code in Flutter and I'm running on Linux and Chrome (web) without any mobile device. When I run my code, I get the following error:

> Unsupported operation: Trying to use the default qrview implementation for
> TargetPlatform.linux but there isn't a default one

Here is a snippet of the code to scan the QR code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class Scanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const Scanner({super.key});

  @override
  _ScannerState createState() => _ScannerState();
}

class _ScannerState extends State<Scanner> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  late QRViewController controller;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(child: Text("Scan the Building QR Code"),),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    QRView(
                      key: qrKey,
                      onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;

    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
      controller.pauseCamera();
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      if (await canLaunch(scanData.code)) {
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        await launch(scanData.code);
        controller.resumeCamera();
      } else {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Could not find viable URL'),
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListBody(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Barcode Type: ${describeEnum(scanData.format)}'),
                    Text('Data: ${scanData.code}'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ).then((value) => controller.resumeCamera());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the screen that I get:

[image: Scan QR Code result]

Answer (score 0):

The package does only support the Android & iOS platform s you can see on https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner